# simple symbol regex solution

Tags: ruby, regex, string

The problem I'm looking at says only inputs with '+' symbols covering any letters in the string is true so like "+d++" or "+d+==+a+" but not

```
"f++d+"
"3+a=+b+"
"++d+=c+"
```

I tried to solve this using regex since it's kind of a string pattern matching problem. /(+[a-z][^+])|([^+.][a-z]+)/ but this does not cover patterns where the letters are at the beginning or end of the string. I need help something more comprehensive.

Comment: did you want to match `+f+g+` ?

Comment: @user3043051 are you alive ??

Comment: We need a question that is more comprehensible.

Comment: sorry watching house of cards I want to match cases that don't result in true so +f+g+ would not be one of those cases. I wrote a regex for it but it's kinda long ([^+][a-z])|([a-z][^+])|(\A[a-z]\+)|(\+[a-z]\Z)

Answer (score 0):

You should try following

```
/^\+{0,2}[a-z0-9]+\+{0,2}(=*\+{0-2}[a-z0-9]+\+{0,2})*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex.

```
^(?:[^\w\n]*\+[a-z]+\+)+[^\w\n]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/1)

If you want to match `+f+g+` also, then put the following `+` inside a positive lookahead assertion.

```
^(?:[^\w\n]*\+[a-z]+(?=\+))+[^\w\n]*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/2)

Comment: `[^\w\n]*` in the above would be written as `\W*`, if the input won't have any line breaks.